# Automatically run an interpreter in VS Code integrated terminal

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

I've set up VS Code to always open a Scala interpreter in all terminals by default with:

```
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "/home/jan/Code/experiments-scala",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-c", "sbt consoleQuick"],
```

(in `.vscode/settings.json`)

This is a rather hacky solution though, obviously I want *just one* terminal to run the interpreter. For example, when VS Code tries to run shell commands (like installing Python tools), it actually first starts a Scala interpreter and tries to run it in them.